# Form Fields Not Enabled By Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Solved - For anyone else experiencing this issue, here are a few suggestions.

1. As pcalkins mentioned in the comments, the tags are dynamic and will change based on untouched, touched or changed. Using the untouched elements helped. If you click in the fields to get the element class value for example, your xpath will be wrong.
2. Selenium had issues with typing certain fields. It would get cut-off after spaces. I ended up writing a new method instead of using find element send keys.

   ```
        public static void TypeAngular (string value, IWebElement element)
    {
        WaitForElementEnabled(element);
        var builder = new Actions(_webDriver);
        var typeAngularText = builder.MoveToElement(element).Click().SendKeys(value).Build();
        typeAngularText.Perform();
    }
   ```

Need some help here. I have not seen this before so after beating it around for a few days, I thought I would see if anyone has a solution. I am trying to add test data into a new payment form but the elements are not found. It is not the iframe! :)

1. The payment form is moving to a app called Rally which appears to use angular and react.
2. Each individual credit card field (name, cc num, exp date etc.) has a unique iframe.
3. I am using C# Selenium and when it hits the payment form, it can't find any of the the payment fields.
4. If I debug it, and manually click on the browser into the credit card number field, it basically enables the entire form and then everything works. I can then continue with the debug and all of the fields populate. Meaning, the iframe values are correct but why is this form not enabled?
5. I have tried a variety of work arounds like clicking submit without the fields being populated so error handling is invoked. The fields are still not enabled. I even tried tabbing in and waiting for the element.
6. I have used c# on angular apps without having to use protractor. I am not sure why this would be different!
7. As an example, I can look for element //input[@class='css-sdjvco invalid empty touched' and @aria-label='Card Number Input'] and it is not found. I click in the field manually and then the element is visible. If you take the code below and save it as html and open it in a browser, the field is not found. Click around in the browser to the left of the text and the xpath will be found. The test env is behind firewalls so I cant really share an actual browser url. But this shows what I mean.

What the code looks like.

```
 <div id="react"> 
<input type="tel" class="css-sdjvco invalid empty touched" autocomplete="cc-number" aria-label="Card Number Input" aria-placeholder="" aria-invalid="true" value="" style="font-size: 14px; color: rgb(34, 31, 32);" />
<input class="autofill-field" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="cc-exp" separator=" / " type="tel" aria-label="Card expiration date" aria-placeholder="" aria-invalid="true" />
<input type="tel" class="autofill-field" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="cc-csc" aria-label="Card Security Code" aria-placeholder="" aria-invalid="true" />
<input type="text" class="autofill-field" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="cc-name" aria-label="Text input" aria-placeholder="" aria-invalid="true" /></div>**


<rally-dynamic-field ng-version="15.2.6" class="rally-field-wrapper ng-star-inserted rally-firstName undefined rally-field-plain">
<div class="rally-field-wrapper rally-form-group">
    <rally-input ng-version="15.2.6" class="ng-star-inserted">
        <input
            rallyvalidator=""
            scrollintoview=""
            class="rally-form-control ng-untouched ng-dirty rally-untouched rally-dirty rally-has-value ng-star-inserted rally-errors-msg-hide"
            name="firstName"
            placeholder=" "
            id="rally-oi3bl3"
            autocomplete="given-name"
            inputmode="text"
            maxlength="512"
            data-rally-hook="input-shipping-firstname"
            disabled=""
        />
        <!---->
        <label for="rally-oi3bl3" class="rally-form-control-label ng-star-inserted"> First Name </label>
        <!----><!----><!---->
    </rally-input>
    <!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!---->
</div>
<!---->
```

---

```
<div class="rally-block rally-border rally-credit-card-payment-block rally-d-block show">
<rally-credit-card-payment config='{"isExpanded":true}' class="ng-tns-c40-3" ng-version="15.2.6" id="rally-1cbj84">
    <div class="ng-tns-c40-3">
        <div class="rally-payment-wrapper rally-credit-card-payment ng-tns-c40-3 expand">
            <div id="payment-methods" class="ng-tns-c40-3">
                <div class="rally-mb-4 ng-tns-c40-3">
                    <div class="rally-credit-card-heading-subheading-wrapper ng-tns-c40-3">
                        <h3 class="rally-heading ng-tns-c40-3">Pay with credit card</h3>
                        <div class="rally-credit-card-icon ng-tns-c40-3"></div>
                        <div class="rally-credit-card-subheading rally-mt-1 ng-tns-c40-3">
                            <div class="rally-secured-icon ng-tns-c40-3"></div>
                            <h5 class="rally-sub-heading ng-tns-c40-3">Secure and encrypted</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!---->
                <div class="rally-pymt-container ng-tns-c40-3 ng-trigger ng-trigger-collapseExpand ng-star-inserted" style="max-height: 460px; overflow: hidden;" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="rally-pymt-loader-container ng-tns-c40-3">
                        <div class="rally-pymt-loader-item ng-tns-c40-3 rally-full-width-shimmer ng-star-inserted" style=""></div>
                        <div class="rally-pymt-loader-item ng-tns-c40-3 rally-full-width-shimmer ng-star-inserted" style=""></div>
                        <div class="rally-pymt-loader-item ng-tns-c40-3 rally-full-width-shimmer ng-star-inserted" style=""></div>
                        <div class="rally-pymt-loader-item ng-tns-c40-3 rally-full-width-shimmer ng-star-inserted" style=""></div>
                        <!---->
                    </div>
                    <rally-payment-form class="ng-tns-c40-3 ng-star-inserted">
                        <!----><!---->
                        <div class="rally-payment-form VGS ng-star-inserted">
                            <!---->
                            <rally-credit-card class="ng-star-inserted">
                                <form novalidate="" class="rally-credit-card ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                                    <div class="rally-card-input rally-credit-card-number ng-star-inserted">
                                        <span class="rally-form-control ng-star-inserted rally-no-value rally-invalid rally-touched" id="vgs-card-number">
                                            <iframe
                                                title="Secure card number input frame"
                                                src="https://js3.verygoodvault.com/vgs-collect/2.18.3/lib/index.html#type=card-number&amp;name=card_number&amp;validations%5B0%5D=required&amp;validations%5B1%5D=validCardNumber&amp;autoComplete=cc-number&amp;color=%23221f20&amp;fontSize=14px&amp;formId=randomId26044203206012501584&amp;fieldId=randomId26028027184394429394&amp;createdAt=1695774141669&amp;tnt=dG50cnNxeXZjZzU%3D&amp;env=c2FuZGJveA%3D%3D&amp;logLevel=default&amp;satellitePort=&amp;vgsCollectSessionId=e6404c4d-8c68-464f-bb59-57fb6c97c73d&amp;css%5Bborder-radius%5D=0.25rem&amp;css%5Bpadding%5D=23px%2015px%208px&amp;css%5Bwidth%5D=calc%28100%25%20-%2030px%29&amp;css%5Bheight%5D=calc%28100%25%20-%2031px%29&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-family%5D=Work%20Sans&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-style%5D=normal&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-weight%5D=500&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-display%5D=swap&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bsrc%5D=url%28https%3A%2F%2Ffonts.gstatic.com%2Fs%2Fworksans%2Fv16%2FQGYsz_wNahGAdqQ43Rh_fKDptfpA4Q.woff2%29%20format%28%22woff2%22%29&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bunicode-range%5D=U%2B0000-00FF%2C%20U%2B0131%2C%20U%2B0152-0153%2C%20U%2B02BB-02BC%2C%20U%2B02C6%2C%20U%2B02DA%2C%20U%2B02DC%2C%20U%2B2000-206F%2C%20U%2B2074%2C%20U%2B20AC%2C%20U%2B2122%2C%20U%2B2191%2C%20U%2B2193%2C%20U%2B2212%2C%20U%2B2215%2C%20U%2BFEFF%2C%20U%2BFFFD&amp;css%5Bfont-family%5D=%22Work%20Sans%22%2C%20sans-serif&amp;css%5Bfont-weight%5D=500"
                                                frameborder="0"
                                                scrolling="0"
                                                allowtransparency="true"
                                                id="randomId26028027184394429394"
                                                form-id="randomId26044203206012501584"
                                            ></iframe>
                                        </span>
                                        <!---->
                                        <span class="rally-error-msg ng-star-inserted">Enter a card number</span>
                                        <!---->
                                        <label class="rally-form-control-label ng-star-inserted" for="vgs-card-number"> Card number </label>
                                        <!----><!----><!---->
                                        <div class="rally-card-brand rally-card-default ng-star-inserted"></div>
                                        <!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rally-card-input rally-cardholder-name ng-star-inserted">
                                        <span class="rally-form-control ng-star-inserted rally-no-value rally-invalid" id="vgs-card-holder">
                                            <iframe
                                                title="Secure text input frame"
                                                src="https://js3.verygoodvault.com/vgs-collect/2.18.3/lib/index.html#type=text&amp;name=card_name&amp;validations%5B0%5D=required&amp;validations%5B1%5D=%2F%5E%5B%5E%5Cu%7B1f300%7D-%5Cu%7B1f5ff%7D%5Cu%7B1f900%7D-%5Cu%7B1f9ff%7D%5Cu%7B1f600%7D-%5Cu%7B1f64f%7D%5Cu%7B1f680%7D-%5Cu%7B1f6ff%7D%5Cu%7B2600%7D-%5Cu%7B26ff%7D%5Cu%7B2700%7D-%5Cu%7B27bf%7D%5Cu%7B1f1e6%7D-%5Cu%7B1f1ff%7D%5Cu%7B1f191%7D-%5Cu%7B1f251%7D%5Cu%7B1f004%7D%5Cu%7B1f0cf%7D%5Cu%7B1f170%7D-%5Cu%7B1f171%7D%5Cu%7B1f17e%7D-%5Cu%7B1f17f%7D%5Cu%7B1f18e%7D%5Cu%7B3030%7D%5Cu%7B2b50%7D%5Cu%7B2b55%7D%5Cu%7B2934%7D-%5Cu%7B2935%7D%5Cu%7B2b05%7D-%5Cu%7B2b07%7D%5Cu%7B2b1b%7D-%5Cu%7B2b1c%7D%5Cu%7B3297%7D%5Cu%7B3299%7D%5Cu%7B303d%7D%5Cu%7B00a9%7D%5Cu%7B00ae%7D%5Cu%7B2122%7D%5Cu%7B23f3%7D%5Cu%7B24c2%7D%5Cu%7B23e9%7D-%5Cu%7B23ef%7D%5Cu%7B25b6%7D%5Cu%7B23f8%7D-%5Cu%7B23fa%7D%5D%2A%24%2Fgu&amp;autoComplete=cc-name&amp;color=%23221f20&amp;fontSize=14px&amp;formId=randomId26044203206012501584&amp;fieldId=randomId2609933357690739868&amp;createdAt=1695774141671&amp;tnt=dG50cnNxeXZjZzU%3D&amp;env=c2FuZGJveA%3D%3D&amp;logLevel=default&amp;satellitePort=&amp;vgsCollectSessionId=e6404c4d-8c68-464f-bb59-57fb6c97c73d&amp;css%5Bborder-radius%5D=0.25rem&amp;css%5Bpadding%5D=23px%2015px%208px&amp;css%5Bwidth%5D=calc%28100%25%20-%2030px%29&amp;css%5Bheight%5D=calc%28100%25%20-%2031px%29&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-family%5D=Work%20Sans&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-style%5D=normal&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-weight%5D=500&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-display%5D=swap&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bsrc%5D=url%28https%3A%2F%2Ffonts.gstatic.com%2Fs%2Fworksans%2Fv16%2FQGYsz_wNahGAdqQ43Rh_fKDptfpA4Q.woff2%29%20format%28%22woff2%22%29&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bunicode-range%5D=U%2B0000-00FF%2C%20U%2B0131%2C%20U%2B0152-0153%2C%20U%2B02BB-02BC%2C%20U%2B02C6%2C%20U%2B02DA%2C%20U%2B02DC%2C%20U%2B2000-206F%2C%20U%2B2074%2C%20U%2B20AC%2C%20U%2B2122%2C%20U%2B2191%2C%20U%2B2193%2C%20U%2B2212%2C%20U%2B2215%2C%20U%2BFEFF%2C%20U%2BFFFD&amp;css%5Bfont-family%5D=%22Work%20Sans%22%2C%20sans-serif&amp;css%5Bfont-weight%5D=500"
                                                frameborder="0"
                                                scrolling="0"
                                                allowtransparency="true"
                                                id="randomId2609933357690739868"
                                                form-id="randomId26044203206012501584"
                                            ></iframe>
                                        </span>
                                        <!---->
                                        <span class="rally-error-msg ng-star-inserted">Enter a name on card</span>
                                        <!---->
                                        <label class="rally-form-control-label ng-star-inserted" for="vgs-card-holder"> Name on card </label>
                                        <!----><!----><!----><!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rally-card-input rally-expiry-date ng-star-inserted">
                                        <span class="rally-form-control ng-star-inserted rally-no-value rally-invalid" id="vgs-card-expiry">
                                            <iframe
                                                title="Secure card expiration date input frame"
                                                src="https://js3.verygoodvault.com/vgs-collect/2.18.3/lib/index.html#type=card-expiration-date&amp;name=card_exp&amp;validations%5B0%5D=required&amp;validations%5B1%5D=validCardExpirationDate&amp;autoComplete=cc-exp&amp;color=%23221f20&amp;fontSize=14px&amp;formId=randomId26044203206012501584&amp;fieldId=randomId2601799340955418558&amp;createdAt=1695774141673&amp;tnt=dG50cnNxeXZjZzU%3D&amp;env=c2FuZGJveA%3D%3D&amp;logLevel=default&amp;satellitePort=&amp;vgsCollectSessionId=e6404c4d-8c68-464f-bb59-57fb6c97c73d&amp;css%5Bborder-radius%5D=0.25rem&amp;css%5Bpadding%5D=23px%2015px%208px&amp;css%5Bwidth%5D=calc%28100%25%20-%2030px%29&amp;css%5Bheight%5D=calc%28100%25%20-%2031px%29&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-family%5D=Work%20Sans&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-style%5D=normal&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-weight%5D=500&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-display%5D=swap&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bsrc%5D=url%28https%3A%2F%2Ffonts.gstatic.com%2Fs%2Fworksans%2Fv16%2FQGYsz_wNahGAdqQ43Rh_fKDptfpA4Q.woff2%29%20format%28%22woff2%22%29&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bunicode-range%5D=U%2B0000-00FF%2C%20U%2B0131%2C%20U%2B0152-0153%2C%20U%2B02BB-02BC%2C%20U%2B02C6%2C%20U%2B02DA%2C%20U%2B02DC%2C%20U%2B2000-206F%2C%20U%2B2074%2C%20U%2B20AC%2C%20U%2B2122%2C%20U%2B2191%2C%20U%2B2193%2C%20U%2B2212%2C%20U%2B2215%2C%20U%2BFEFF%2C%20U%2BFFFD&amp;css%5Bfont-family%5D=%22Work%20Sans%22%2C%20sans-serif&amp;css%5Bfont-weight%5D=500"
                                                frameborder="0"
                                                scrolling="0"
                                                allowtransparency="true"
                                                id="randomId2601799340955418558"
                                                form-id="randomId26044203206012501584"
                                            ></iframe>
                                        </span>
                                        <!---->
                                        <span class="rally-error-msg ng-star-inserted">Enter an expiration date (mm/yy)</span>
                                        <!---->
                                        <label class="rally-form-control-label ng-star-inserted" for="vgs-card-expiry"> Expiration date (MM/YY) </label>
                                        <!----><!----><!----><!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rally-card-input rally-cvv ng-star-inserted">
                                        <span class="rally-form-control ng-star-inserted rally-no-value rally-invalid" id="vgs-card-cvc">
                                            <iframe
                                                title="Secure card security code input frame"
                                                src="https://js3.verygoodvault.com/vgs-collect/2.18.3/lib/index.html#type=card-security-code&amp;name=card_cvc&amp;validations%5B0%5D=required&amp;validations%5B1%5D=validCardSecurityCode&amp;autoComplete=cc-csc&amp;color=%23221f20&amp;fontSize=14px&amp;formId=randomId26044203206012501584&amp;fieldId=randomId2604204857032745133&amp;createdAt=1695774141675&amp;tnt=dG50cnNxeXZjZzU%3D&amp;env=c2FuZGJveA%3D%3D&amp;logLevel=default&amp;satellitePort=&amp;vgsCollectSessionId=e6404c4d-8c68-464f-bb59-57fb6c97c73d&amp;css%5Bborder-radius%5D=0.25rem&amp;css%5Bpadding%5D=23px%2015px%208px&amp;css%5Bwidth%5D=calc%28100%25%20-%2030px%29&amp;css%5Bheight%5D=calc%28100%25%20-%2031px%29&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-family%5D=Work%20Sans&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-style%5D=normal&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-weight%5D=500&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bfont-display%5D=swap&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bsrc%5D=url%28https%3A%2F%2Ffonts.gstatic.com%2Fs%2Fworksans%2Fv16%2FQGYsz_wNahGAdqQ43Rh_fKDptfpA4Q.woff2%29%20format%28%22woff2%22%29&amp;css%5B%40font-face%5D%5Bunicode-range%5D=U%2B0000-00FF%2C%20U%2B0131%2C%20U%2B0152-0153%2C%20U%2B02BB-02BC%2C%20U%2B02C6%2C%20U%2B02DA%2C%20U%2B02DC%2C%20U%2B2000-206F%2C%20U%2B2074%2C%20U%2B20AC%2C%20U%2B2122%2C%20U%2B2191%2C%20U%2B2193%2C%20U%2B2212%2C%20U%2B2215%2C%20U%2BFEFF%2C%20U%2BFFFD&amp;css%5Bfont-family%5D=%22Work%20Sans%22%2C%20sans-serif&amp;css%5Bfont-weight%5D=500"
                                                frameborder="0"
                                                scrolling="0"
                                                allowtransparency="true"
                                                id="randomId2604204857032745133"
                                                form-id="randomId26044203206012501584"
                                                name="vgs-collect-cvv-field"
                                            ></iframe>
                                        </span>
                                        <!---->
                                        <span class="rally-error-msg ng-star-inserted">Enter a security code</span>
                                        <!---->
                                        <label class="rally-form-control-label ng-star-inserted" for="vgs-card-cvc"> Security code </label>
                                        <!----><!----><!----><!---->
                                    </div>
                                    <!---->
                                </form>
                                <!---->
                            </rally-credit-card>
                            <!---->
                        </div>
                        <!---->
                    </rally-payment-form>
                    <!----><!---->
                    <rally-payment-form class="ng-tns-c40-3 ng-star-inserted" hidden="">
                        <!----><!---->
                        <div class="rally-payment-form adyen ng-star-inserted">
                            <!---->
                            <rally-credit-card class="ng-star-inserted">
                                <form novalidate="" class="rally-credit-card ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="rally-c0okfe">
                                    <div class="rally-card-input rally-credit-card-number ng-star-inserted">
                                        <span class="rally-form-control ng-star-inserted rally-invalid rally-no-value" id="adyen-encryptedCardNumber" data-cse="encryptedCardNumber">
                                            <iframe
                                                src="https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/securedfields/test_BHLRFQIJABHAJNHMPR4LUJKZHMEUOLJX/4.4.1/securedFields.html?type=card&amp;d=aHR0cHM6Ly9wb3Bzb2NrZXRzLWxsYy5zYW5kYm94Lm9ucmFsbHkuY29t"
                                                class="js-iframe"
                                                title="Iframe for card number"
                                                allowtransparency="true"
                                                style="border: none; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;"
                                                referrerpolicy="origin"
                                            >
                                                <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
                                            </iframe>
                                        </span>
                                        <!---->
                                        <span class="rally-error-msg ng-star-inserted">Enter a card number</span>
                                        <!---->
                                        <label class="rally-form-control-label ng-star-inserted" for="adyen-encryptedCardNumber"> Card number </label>
                                        <!----><!----><!---->
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking specific coordinates with javascript? That could be one way to simulate your currently manual click. Maybe some clever actionchain will also do the trick.

Comment: Is the HTML in your question the **rendered** HTML source, or the Angular template file?

Comment: Thanks all. Greg it is the rendered html.

Comment: You don't show the DOM of the iframe's which is where those inputs are.  Right-click in there and choose "Inspect"... you can copy from there.  (open the document node if necessary)  Angular will change the field's class attributes based on state.  For instance, "touched" means that this input field has been unfocused, "untouched" means it has never had focus... "pristine" means the user hasn't changed anything in the field, while "dirty" happens once the user has changed something.

Comment: In addition these "<rally-dynamic-field", "<rally-input" tags will be processed by JS, so you need to right-click and choose "Inspect" to get the current state of the DOM, as JS will replace those.

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for the reply - added the elements from those 2 fields.

Comment: I'd use the ID or "data-rally-hook" attributes to target those... for the iframes, if you aren't seeing DOM code there, I'm not sure what's happening, but it's possible these are sandboxed iframes that would not allow JS calls to get at the elements.  Though manual clicking wouldn't help if that were the case.  When you switch the driver to these iframes, be sure to use a WebDriverWait with ExpectedCondition of "frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt"  For more specific advice you should include your code.

Comment: Will take a look. Yeah this is definitely a sandbox since it is in the lower envs.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for the help. Based on your suggestions, I found that when I drilled down further, I found the xpath for the field where they have "empty" in class name. Using these I am able to type in the fields now to a point. CC Num and Exp Date are typing up to the space or the / and stopping.  So I get 1234 and nothing after and then the exp date I get 01/ and missing the year. Getting closer!

Comment: Solved. Appreciate the help everyone.